# How to use the type String as a parameter?

Tags: string, scala, switch-statement

```
    object UtilitiesHelper extends App {
      override def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
        def convert(value: String, targetType: Any): Any = {
          targetType match {
            case _: Int => value.toInt
            case _: Float => value.toFloat
            case _: Double => value.toDouble
            case _: String => value
          }
        }

        def convert2(value: String, targetType: Any): Any = {
          targetType match {
            case Int => value.toInt
            case Float => value.toFloat
            case Double => value.toDouble
            // Hack #1
            case _ => value
            // Ideally we want
            //case String => value
          }
        }

        println(convert("1", 1))
        println(convert("1.0", 1.0))
        println(convert("Hello world", ""))

        println(convert2("1", Int))
        println(convert2("1.0", Double))
        // Hack #2
        println(convert2("Hello world", "".getClass()))
        // Ideally we want
        //println(convert2("Hello world", String)))
      }
    }
```

What's the proper way to accomplish what hack #1 and #2 is doing?

I can't figure out why convert2("1", String) gives a compile-time error (with the message "object java.lang.String is not a value") whereas convert2("1", Int) compiles and runs perfectly fine. Does it have something to do with Int being a Scala native type and String being an alias for java.lang.String?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I came up to something like this. It is a bit more complicated, but it works for me.

```
trait Converter[T] {
  def convert(value: String): T
}

object ConvertExample extends Application {
  implicit object IntConverter extends Converter[Int] {
    def convert(value: String) = value.toInt
  }

  implicit object StringConverter extends Converter[String] {
    def convert(value: String) = value.toString
  }

  def convert[T](value: String)(implicit converter: Converter[T]): T = converter.convert(value)

  println(convert[Int]("3"))
  println(convert[String]("asdasd"))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code works with `Int` because there is an object called `object Int`, defined somewhere, the same not being true for `String`. That said, you can write your code by using a type parameter, like so:

```
def convert2[T](value: String): T = {
  // do something...
}
```